# Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
program test
integer, dimension(3,3) :: a =(/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/)
do i=1,3
write(*,*) (a(i,j),j=1,3)
enddo
end program
```

I get the following error:

> Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)

Is the initialization method wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Currently you are trying to assign a 1D array (of length `9`) to a 2D (`3x3`) array. You need to `reshape` the array before the assignment:

```
program test
  integer, dimension(3,3) :: a = reshape( (/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/), (/ 3,3/))
  do i=1,3
    write(*,*) (a(i,j),j=1,3)
  enddo
end program
```